# Collapse table rows on page load

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery that collapses some table rows on click. Is there a way to change it so that it loads collapsed as opposed to opened?

HTML:

```
<table class="mob-table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="collapse">
        <td class="mob-dark">Listing - First Last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: First Last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email: test@test.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number: 123-456-7890</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="collapse">
        <td class="mob-dark">Listing - First Last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: First Last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email: test@test.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number: 123-456-7890</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.collapse').click(function(){
     $(this).nextUntil('tr.collapse').toggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8jeb5me/)

Comment: Short answer: Try replacing `$('.collapse').click` with just `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('tbody > tr:not(.collapse)').hide();
```

see demo [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8jeb5me/1/)

if you want to use css you can use a same selector

```
tbody > tr:not(.collapse){
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to achieve that with CSS (IMHO a more suitable solution):

```
.collapse ~ tr{
    display: none;
}
```

this hides all the `.collapse` `tr`'s siblings right when you load the page. The `click` event is still bound to the `.collapse` elements and will work on click.

Have a look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0f8c33e/) for a working example

If you need to stick with `jQuery` you can:

1) hide all `.collapse` tr siblings:

```
$(".collapse").siblings("tr").toggle(); //--- or hide() in your case
```

2) trigger the click event on your `.collapse` elements in order to hide them

```
$(".collapse").trigger("click");
```